# Change ESXi security settings via CLI

Tags: command-line, vmware, esxi

Is there a way to change security settings of an ESXi (6.7u2) via CLI ?
Standard advanced settings can be modified by the following command :

```
esxcli system settings advanced set -o /Mem/ShareForceSalting -i 2
```

Or kernel settings can be change with the command :

```
esxcli system settings kernel set -s hyperthreading -v FALSE
```

But I can't fin a way to change security parameters from CLI (it's okay with GUI).
For instance, I'm unable to change theses parameters from CLI :

- Security.AccountUnlockTime
- Security.AccountLockFailures
- ...

Can someone help on that ?

Comment: What is the full property name for ShareForceSalting?  I would imagine it would be something like *Memory.SharedForceSalting*?

Comment: The full property name is Mem.ShareForceSalting.

Comment: I assume you tried `/Security/ShareForceSalting`?

Comment: Yes, and the error is : `Unable to find branch Security.`

Answer (score 0):

The security settings are not listed in available parameters with

`esxcli system settings advanced list | grep “Security”`.

I haven’t found also in other namespaces like `security` and `account`.

But you can manage this settings via PowerCLI :

```
Set-VMHostAdvancedConfiguration Security.AccountLockFailures -Value 10

Set-VMHostAdvancedConfiguration Security.AccountUnlockTime -Value 100
```

References:
https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2015/10/14/manage-vsphere-6-security-policy-via--esxcli.aspx

https://www.vmwareblog.org/cool-vsphere-command-line-interface-esxcli-commands-helped-lot/

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I've already seen the PowerCLI solution but in fact I have no administration machine and no guest machine (when I need to secure the ESXi). I need to look into vim-cmd options.